# How does int() in Python know if a number is a float?

Tags: python, try-catch

Usually if you put int(a) or int(b) it will convert "a" and "b" into integers

If I try print(int(4.5)) it will print 4

But if I try it in a try statement:

```
def zero_dev(num1, num2):
    try:
        a = int(num1)/int(num2)
        return int(a)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 'Zero Division Exception: integer division or modulo by zero'
    except ValueError:
        try:
            val = int(num1)
            pass
        except ValueError:
            return f"Input Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{num1}'"
        try:
            val1 = int(num2)
        except ValueError:
            return f"Input Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{num2}'"
    
    
num_a = input()
num_b = input()
print(zero_dev(num_a, num_b))
```

Edit:
If num1 = 4 and num2 = 4.5

How come Python didn't convert num2 into an integer?

Previously int() would convert a float into an integer.

But here it doesn't convert it, it tells me "num2" has a base of 10, it is not an integer.

Comment: What is `num_2`? Please provide a [mcve]. Don't provide code that requires user inputs when your question isnt' about user inputs **just give us that data**. Almost none of this is relevant to your question. Are you asking why something like `int("4.5")` will raise an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`input()` always returns a string**. So `num_a = input(...)` makes `num_a` a string.

`int()` won't convert floats-as-strings to integers:

```py
>>> int(3.4)  # ok
3
>>> int("3")  # ok
3
>>> int("3.4")  # not ok
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.4'
```

But `float()` has no problems with string inputs of floats or ints:

```py
>>> float("3.4")
3.4
>>> float("3")
3.0
```

So combine that to get the behaviour you want - first convert the input (which is a string) to a `float` and then to an `int`:

```py
>>> int(float("3.4"))
3
```